# LINT-34 (warning) In design '%s', three-state bus '%s' has non three- state driver '%s'

Tags: warnings, driver, verilog, lint, synthesis

I am trying to synthesize a program I created in Verilog using Design Vision.
I get multiple of the following warnings:

> Warning: In design 'mergeTOP', three-state bus 'state[0]' has non
>   three-state driver 'u1/state_reg[0]/Q'. (LINT-34)
>
> Warning: In design 'mergeTOP', three-state bus 'temp_in5[0]' has non
>   three-state driver 'u1/temp_in05_reg[0]/Q'. (LINT-34)

DESCRIPTION
       Synopsys libraries contain descriptions of three-state driving pins  on
       components.   Synopsys  tools classify a net as a three-state net if it
       is driven by at least one pin  that  has  this  three-state  attribute.
       Normally,  if  there  are  multiple drivers on such nets, it is assumed
       that all driving pins should be three-state drivers, for correct opera-
       tion  of  the three-state bus.  This warning message indicates a situa-
       tion where at least one non-three-state driver appears on a three-state
       net.

```
/*======Declarations===============================*/
module controller (clock, reset, start, state,  temp_in1, temp_in2, temp_in3, temp_in4, temp_in5, done, temp_out1, temp_out2, temp_out3, temp_out4, temp_out5, out, in);

/*-----------Inputs--------------------------------*/
    input clock, reset, start;
    input [255:0] in;
    input [255:0] temp_out1, temp_out2, temp_out3, temp_out4, temp_out5;

/*-----------Outputs--------------------------------*/  
    output [5:0] state;
//  output [255:0] temp_in01, temp_in02, temp_in03, temp_in04, temp_in05;
    output done;
    output [255:0] out;
    output [255:0] temp_in1, temp_in2, temp_in3, temp_in4, temp_in5;

/*----------------Nets and Registers----------------*/  
    reg [5:0] state, n_state;
    reg [255:0] temp_in01, temp_in02, temp_in03, temp_in04, temp_in05;
    reg done;
    reg [255:0] out;

always@(posedge clock) // at the posedge of the clock the current state changes based on whether reset is active or the next state determined by the logic.
begin
    if (!reset) // if the active low reset is triggered the state is set to 0.
    state <= 6'b000000;
else // if reset is high or inactive the current state gets the value of the next state.
    state <= n_state;
end

always@* begin // control path
case (state)
6'b000000: begin // state S0, wait for input.
    if (start == 1)
        n_state = 6'b000001;
    else
        n_state = 6'b000000;
end
6'b000001: begin // state S1
    n_state = 6'b000010;
end
6'b000010: begin // state S2
    n_state = 6'b000100;
end
6'b000100: begin // state S3
    n_state = 6'b001000;
end
6'b001000: begin // state S4
    n_state = 6'b010000;
end
6'b010000: begin // state S5
    n_state = 6'b100000;
end
6'b100000: begin // state S5
    n_state = 6'b100000;
end
default: n_state = 6'b000000;
endcase
end

always@(posedge clock) begin
if (!reset) begin
    temp_in01 <= 0;
    out <= 0;
    done <= 0;
end
else begin
    case(state)
    6'b000000: begin
                temp_in01 <= in; 
                out <= in;
                done <= 0;
    end
    6'b000001: begin
                temp_in02 <= temp_out1; 
                out <= temp_out1;
                done <= 0;
    end
    6'b000010: begin
                temp_in03 <= temp_out2; 
                out <= temp_out2;
                done <= 0;
    end
    6'b000100: begin
                temp_in04 <= temp_out3; 
                out <= temp_out3;
                done <= 0;
    end
    6'b001000: begin
                temp_in05 <= temp_out4; 
                out <= temp_out4;
                done <= 0;
    end
    6'b010000: begin
                out <= temp_out5;
                done <= 0;
    end
    6'b100000: begin
                out <= out;
                done <= 1;
    end
    default: begin
                out <= out;
                done <= 0;
    end
endcase
end 
end


assign  temp_in5 = temp_in05;
assign  temp_in4 = temp_in04;
assign  temp_in3 = temp_in03;
assign  temp_in2 = temp_in02;
assign  temp_in1 = temp_in01;


endmodule


`

/*======Declarations===============================*/
module mergeTOP (clock, reset, start, in, out, done);

/*-----------Inputs--------------------------------*/
    input [255:0] in;
    input clock, reset, start;

/*-----------Outputs--------------------------------*/  
    output [255:0] out;
    output done;

/*----------------Nets and Registers----------------*/  
//  reg [255:0] out;
//  reg done;
    wire [5:0] state;
    wire [255:0] temp_out1, temp_out2, temp_out3, temp_out4, temp_out5;
    wire [255:0] temp_in1, temp_in2, temp_in3, temp_in4, temp_in5;

controller u1 (.clock(clock), .reset(reset), .start(start), .state(state), .done(done), .out(out), .in(in),
            .temp_in1(temp_in1), .temp_in2(temp_in2), .temp_in3(temp_in3), .temp_in4(temp_in4), .temp_in5(temp_in5),
            .temp_out1(temp_out1), .temp_out2(temp_out2), .temp_out3(temp_out3), .temp_out4(temp_out4), .temp_out5(temp_out5)
            );
merge1 #(16) u2 (.in(temp_in1),.out(temp_out1),.state(state));
merge1 #(32) u3 (.in(temp_in2),.out(temp_out2),.state(state));
merge1 #(64) u4 (.in(temp_in3),.out(temp_out3),.state(state));
merge1 #(128) u5 (.in(temp_in4),.out(temp_out4),.state(state));
merge1 #(256) u6 (.in(temp_in5),.out(temp_out5),.state(state));


endmodule
```

Comment: merge1 is just a module that sorts the 8 bit registers using  mergesort algorithm. I added a description that design vision provides me, but I am fairly new to this stuff and I don't quite understand how to fix this.

Comment: Please share your `merge1` code.I'm guessing it is assigning value to `state` and `temp_in*`.